# C++ CLI two stack<>

Tags: c++-cli

problems in use two cliext::stack..

```
stack<T^>^ pfn = gcnew stack<T^>();  - compiles     
stack<K^>^ pf = gcnew stack<K^>();  - 93 compile errors.
```

What is the problem?

USE Generics::Stack Why is the declaration of the two machines a lot of mistakes?

```
private: System::Void btn_add_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    fileOperation^ fw = gcnew fileOperation();
    if (comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 0 ) 
    {
        flyBird^ f = gcnew flyBird();
        System::Collections::Generic::Stack<flyBird^>^ p =  gcnew   System::Collections::Generic::Stack<flyBird^>();

        f->birdName=txt_name->Text;
        f-> year    = textBox1->Text;
        f->vess = txt_tmp1->Text;
        f->sreda = txt_tmp2->Text;
        p->Push(f);
    }
    else 
    {
        System::Collections::Generic::Stack<noflyBird^>^ p1 = gcnew     System::Collections::Generic::Stack<noflyBird^>();
        noFlyBird^ f = gcnew noFlyBird();
        fn ->birdName=txt_name->Text;
        fn ->year = textBox1->Text;
        fn ->pitanie = txt_tmp1->Text;
        fn ->domoshnie = txt_tmp2->Text;*/
    }
}
```

```
Warning 1   warning C4138: '*/' found outside of comment    c:\documents and settings\bobilev\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\burd\burd\Form1.h    275 1   burd
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  \my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\burd\burd\Form1.h 277 1   burd
Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  ments\visual studio 2010\projects\burd\burd\Form1.h 281 1   burd
Error   11  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\burd\burd\Form1.h  293 1   burd
Error   12  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  c:\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\burd\burd\Form1.h   297 1   burd
```

Comment: I think you need to add a CLI tag because this makes no sense in standard C++.

Comment: Without seeing the errors it's impossible to answer, but might have something to do with the differences between `T` and `K`?

Comment: the first two errors in the list   error: C3156: 'fileOperation::FileReader::Form1' : you cannot a local definition of a manged type
error c2653 : Form1: is a not class or namespace name

Comment: What types are `T` and `K`? Does using `pf` alone work?

Comment: The STL/CLR library was a giant mistake.  Don't bother with it, use the Stack class in the System::Collections::Generic namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the compile errors you have, the first is an extra `*/` end comment without a `/*` to begin the comment. We can see that in the code you posted, at the end of the else block. That error is on line 275 of your code. The other compile errors you posted are on line 277 and later, so it looks like the problem is AFTER the code you posted here.